# From a lat long position knowing if that point its inside a circle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coordinates, postgis

So i have a model that saves latlong data. And i want to make a methode that i give a point_x, point_y , and sees if my Location model has a point that is near 500m or less.

Here is an exemple of points:

```
Location.longlat.x = 43.3233
Location.lonlat.y = 23.3233

point_x = 32.3233
point_y = 23.323
```

I store those longlat coordinates using postgis for my model. So far i know its save them as spherical points and are º.
So is there a method to define them as plane points and calculate if they are close to 500m or less ?

Edit: This is how i store longlat coordinates in my model:

```
t.geography "longlat", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"st_point", :geographic=>true}
```

EDIT: script that im trying to use

```
  ForecastLocation.all.each do |forecast_location|
     ForecastLocation.where("ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_MakePoint(
       {forecast_location.longlat.x},#{forecast_location.longlat.y}),
        ST_MakePoint(#{circle_x},#{circle_y})<500")
```

ForecastLocation = is model name

longlat= column defined above , saves x,y

circle_x
circle_y = variables that makes the main point, and compare this one to all my ForecastLocation.longlat

What im tring is to do same thing as in the answer with the select , but just to have all objects that are closer than 500m of circle

Comment: Don't store coordinates, store a `geometry` or `geography`. Then this will become simple.

Comment: There's [`ST_DistanceSphere`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.2/ST_DistanceSphere.html) to calculate the distance between points on a sphere.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i added how its that column in my schema

Comment: @Stefan Sorry but that exemple is way to much to understand. Could you provide a more simple one  or explain it a little bit ?

Comment: That doesn't look like SQL...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM locations WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(x, y), ST_MakePoint(32.3233, 23.323)) <= 500` should work. Replace `locations` with your actual your table name and `x` and `y` with your lat / long column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the distance (in meters) between two points on a sphere via [`ST_DistanceSphere`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.2/ST_DistanceSphere.html):

```sql
SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(
  ST_MakePoint(43.3233, 23.3233),
  ST_MakePoint(32.3233, 23.323)
);
--> 1122927.11865462
```

To select all locations within 500 meters, you could use something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM locations
WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(
  ST_MakePoint(x, y),
  ST_MakePoint(32.3233, 23.323)
) <= 500;
```

where `locations` is your table and `x` / `y` are your lat / long columns.

Comment: I did use this and works but cant see objects that are in that search. Error i have is object doesn't support #inspect

Comment: @CodrinM not sure what kind of object you got there that doesn't support `inspect`. How did you run the query?

Comment: i updated the question with the little script im trying to use. Im trying to use that query in a ruby file, so i can make a method to define a point and compare all my objects and  see if wich ones are close. If you could help would be great, if not just let me know so i edit back and make another question.